# Query where not in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that is called 'groups' and an other table that is called 'subscriptions'.

I want to return all the groups where an user is not subscribed to.

Basically this is the condition I want to negate (let's assume for user with id = 1, status is just a check if the group is activated or not):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM groups g
  LEFT 
  JOIN subscriptions s
    ON s.groups = g.id 
 WHERE g.status = 1 
   AND s.user = 1
```

This query selects all the groups where the user has subscribed, but I need those where he didn't. My problem is that there is nothing into the table related to this user when he has not subscribed, so if I use something like != it will return something that I don't need.

I thought by using NOT IN or NOT EXISTS but I'm not able to let it work.

Do you guys have a quick and performant solution? 
Thank you very much

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (not images.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More the condition on the *second* table to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM `groups` G LEFT JOIN
     `subscriptions` S
     ON G.id = S.groups AND S.user = 1
WHERE G.status = '1';
```

I am guessing that `user` is really a number, which is why I removed the quotes.  In any case, only use quotes for string and date constants, not for numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your tips, I'm still getting all the results (so also the one where the user has subscribed) but now I can see that there is a NULL value in those where he's not into, so I can add into my where condition something like S.user IS NULL

Comment: @Ame:  and voila, now you have the pattern for an *anti-join*... the LEFT JOIN to find matching rows, and then the condition in the WHERE clause that excludes rows that had a match, leaving only the rows that did *not* have a match.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
SELECT * FROM groups g where g.ID not in(select groups from subscriptions)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` to get the record which has related to other record

```
SELECT * FROM `groups` AS G INNER JOIN `subscriptions` AS S ON G.id = S.groups WHERE G.status = '1' AND S.user = '1'
```